# javafx barchart bar colors

Tags: css, javafx

I am trying to change the color of all the bars of a series in javafx barcharts.
See for example: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/bar-chart.htm:

All the bars for 2005 are in `series3` and are painted in light blue.
I would like to paint them, say, in red.

The css has the `.data<n>.chart-bar` selectors, but they change the colors of all the bars
at the same position in all series, and not those of a same serie.
E.g. `.data0.chart-bar` would change all the colors for Austria.
Does anyone know a solution?

Answer (score 3):

Oh.. I know I had this in here somewhere....

Aha! found it! change these properties to the colors you want, for your example, to change `series3` it would be the `.default-color2.chart-bar` bit:

```
.default-color0.chart-bar { -fx-bar-fill: #f9d900; }
.default-color1.chart-bar { -fx-bar-fill: #a9e200; }
.default-color2.chart-bar { -fx-bar-fill: #22bad9; }
.default-color3.chart-bar { -fx-bar-fill: #0181e2; }
.default-color4.chart-bar { -fx-bar-fill: #2f357f; }
.default-color5.chart-bar { -fx-bar-fill: #860061; }
.default-color6.chart-bar { -fx-bar-fill: #c62b00; }
.default-color7.chart-bar { -fx-bar-fill: #ff5700; }
```

To help in the future, here's the link to [caspian.css](http://pastebin.com/0PebD9nR) (default stylesheet for Java 7) and [modena.css](https://bitbucket.org/openjfxmirrors/openjfx-8-master-rt/raw/tip/modules/controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css) (default stylesheet for Java 8) which are perhaps the most useful files in javafx css land, ever. They list every default style that gets applied to javafx, and therefore, lists most (not all) of the properties you could ever want to override in javafx with your own .css Good luck!